# iOS : Unit test SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, sprite-kit

I need help creating unit tests for a simple word game I am developing on sprite kit.
I need to test state of arrays while SKNodes are moving so it includes UI testing too.
Reference to any blog post or any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: please describe what exactly you are having problems with

Comment: I need to do UI Testing for SKNodes so is instruments supports it? Yes, then any good reference for it?
No, then whats the alternative to do UI testing for game developed on Sprite Kit?

Comment: Instruments has nothing to do with unit tests. Xcode's unit testing framework doesn't handle automated UI testing (unit testing != automated UI testing). The normal way to set up unit testing with SK is no different than with other code - create a SKView and SKScene in setup and run your tests. What you **can not** test are things that require timing (ie actions, update and other callbacks, physics) or require the view to refresh (aka UI testing).

Comment: Yup, good answer.
Actually, I am developing a words with friend type game so I want to automate the drag and drop actions and then, unit test words making & matching algo and score calculation

Comment: Then make sure your algorithms have no references to Sprite Kit and you can unit test the hell out of them. It's good design anyway to keep logic/data separate from visuals (ie nodes, actions)

Comment: Yup, I am planning to do so. I developed many apps on java and ran unit tests. iOS is new for me please LearnCocos2D help me with the unit testing on iOS. 
I will study about implementing the design patterns to keep my models(Tile,rack,etc) and controllers as separate as possible from View(Sknodes, etc)

Comment: then read through this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTestYourApp/UnitTestYourApp.html With previous UT experience this should be easy-peasy.

Comment: I am guessing the correct question would be references for UI Testing of Sprite Kit based app?